# Antlr4 visitor functions wrap the result in an array (more precisely in accept function)

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I was writing antlr4 parser, using target language JavaScript, and I need to use visitor to get custom output from my tree (one array, every tree level on other array level). But I get some troubles with returning values from visit functions, when I try to return value from every visit function I get result wrapped in array (I don't need this). I tried to debug my code, but I can't truely see a code part in antlr4 library when this array is created (probably when accept function return a value, accept called inside visitChildren method). I have default operations that work as a chain until value match with concrete operation (expression -> relation -> add -> mult -> etc.).

visitor.js:

```
visitFormula(ctx) {
    let result = [];

    for (let i = 1; i < ctx.getChildCount() - 1; i++) {
      let part = this.visit(ctx.getChild(i));
      result.push(part);
    }

    console.log("formula " + JSON.stringify(result));

    return result;
  }

  // Visit a parse tree produced by MyGrammarParser#expo.
  visitExpo(ctx) {
    let result = this.visitChildren(ctx);
    console.log("expo " + JSON.stringify(result));
    return result;
  }

  // Visit a parse tree produced by MyGrammarParser#unary.ex
  visitUnary(ctx) {
    let result = this.visitChildren(ctx);
    console.log("unary " + JSON.stringify(result));
    return result;
  }



  // Visit a parse tree produced by MyGrammarParser#mult.
  visitMult(ctx) {
    let result = this.visitChildren(ctx);
    console.log("mult " + JSON.stringify(result));
    return result;
  }

  // Visit a parse tree produced by MyGrammarParser#add.
  visitAdd(ctx) {
    let result = this.visitChildren(ctx);
    console.log("add " + JSON.stringify(result));
    return result;
  }

  visitTerm(ctx) {
    if (this.isTerminalNode(ctx)) {
        console.log("term " + JSON.stringify(ctx.getText()));
        return ctx.getText();
    }
    let result = this.visitChildren(ctx);
    console.log("term " + JSON.stringify(result));

    return result;
  }

  visitFunction(ctx) {
    let result = [ctx.FUNCTION_NAME().getText()];

    const expressionList = ctx.expression();

    for (let i = 0; i < expressionList.length; i++) {
      console.log("FUNC ARGS", expressionList[i].getText());
      let part = this.visit(expressionList[i]);
      result.push(part);
    }
    console.log("function " + JSON.stringify(result));
    return result;
  }
```

parser.g4:

```
formula : ST expression EOF;

expo: unary (CARRET unary)*;

unary : (ADD | negation)* term;

negation : SUB;

mult : expo ((MUL | DIV) expo)*;

add : mult ((ADD | SUB) mult)*;

relation
    :   add (RELATION_SYMBOL add)*
    ;

expression
    :   relation ((AND | OR) relation)*
    ;

function
    :   FUNCTION_NAME OPEN_ROUND_BRACKET (expression (COMMA expression)*)? CLOSE_ROUND_BRACKET
    ;

term : function | INTEGER | DECIMAL | PERCENT | reference | OPEN_ROUND_BRACKET expression CLOSE_ROUND_BRACKET;
```

index.js:

```
const formula = "=IF($I$11=D169,1,0)";
var chars = new InputStream(formula, true);
var lexer = new MyGrammarLexer(chars);
var tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
var parser = new MyGrammarParser(tokens);


const tree = parser.formula();

const visitor = new GrammarParserVisitor(); // FormulaWalker 

let res = visitor.visitFormula(tree);
console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```

I can show part of the result (when visting this input's `=IF($I$11=D169,1,0)` third parameter), that i get from console.log in visit functions:

```
term "0"
unary ["0"]
expo [["0"]]
mult [[["0"]]]
add [[[["0"]]]]
relation [[[[["0"]]]]]
```

But I need just to return string without wrapping it in arrays. Why I get this problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: First, you need to define a visit method for every parser rule. Do not rely on the runtime to return the correct result. E.g., for "negation", "relation", etc. Second, it's wrapping in an array because your visit methods all create a "result" array and push the child result into that. Test the number of children first, and if only one child, just return the child result--do not push the child result onto an array. Third, sort your visit methods according to the grammar. It's hard to match up the method with that in the grammar when you have to jump all over the code--bad programming style.

Comment: @kaby76, but I'm pushing into 'result' in visitFormula method, that is always a root node and called only from index.js file. In othes visitor methods I only return results (sometimes also arrays), but after returning it, I get that value wrapped into one more array. I found with debugger when it creates this array (after returning result from antlr4 function), so it's plobably not a problem on side of my custom visit methods. So I'm trying to find solution.

Comment: And it's a part of my visitor, I have this problem in every other (all defined)

Comment: @BartKiers ok, but in the situation when a child can be for example expression and reference in other situations, can I check what rule exactly it is? And if that rule will be also somewhere in the other part of the tree (not only after some parser rule), it won't call for example `visitExpression()` for every existing expression rule (also for expressions, that are in the other part of a tree)?
Maybe I can use also `visit()` where I can pass the child's context in the parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start for a visitor in JavaScript. I simplified your grammar a little bit (yes, know this is not correct, but this is just a demo):

```
grammar MyGrammar;

formula    : ST expression EOF;
expo       : unary (CARRET unary)*;
unary      : (ADD | negation)* term;
negation   : SUB;
mult       : expo ((MUL | DIV) expo)*;
add        : mult ((ADD | SUB) mult)*;
relation   : add (rel_op add)*;
expression : relation ((AND | OR) relation)*;
function   : FUNCTION_NAME OPEN_ROUND_BRACKET (expression (COMMA expression)*)? CLOSE_ROUND_BRACKET;
term       : function | INTEGER | DECIMAL | PERCENT | reference | OPEN_ROUND_BRACKET expression CLOSE_ROUND_BRACKET;
reference  : CELL;
rel_op     : RELATION_SYMBOL | ST;

INTEGER             : [0-9]+;
DECIMAL             : INTEGER '.' INTEGER;
PERCENT             : '%';
CELL                : [A-Z] INTEGER;
ST                  : '=';
CARRET              : '^';
ADD                 : '+';
SUB                 : '-';
MUL                 : '*';
DIV                 : '/';
COMMA               : ',';
AND                 : 'AND';
OR                  : 'OR';
OPEN_ROUND_BRACKET  : '(';
CLOSE_ROUND_BRACKET : ')';
RELATION_SYMBOL     : '>=' | '>' | '<=' | '<';
FUNCTION_NAME       : [A-Z]+;
```

A visitor might look like this:

```js
import MyGrammarVisitor from "./MyGrammarVisitor.js";

export default class DemoVisitor extends MyGrammarVisitor {

  // formula : ST expression EOF;
  visitFormula(ctx) {
    return this.visit(ctx.expression());
  }

  // expo: unary (CARRET unary)*;
  visitExpo(ctx) {
    // TODO account for multiple `unary`s
    return this.visit(ctx.unary(0));
  }

  // unary : (ADD | negation)* term;
  visitUnary(ctx) {
    return this.visit(ctx.term());
  }

  // negation : SUB;
  visitNegation(ctx) {
    throw new Error('TODO: negation')
  }

  // mult : expo ((MUL | DIV) expo)*;
  visitMult(ctx) {
    // TODO account for multiple `expo`s
    return this.visit(ctx.expo(0));
  }

  // add : mult ((ADD | SUB) mult)*;
  visitAdd(ctx) {
    // TODO account for multiple `mult`s
    return this.visit(ctx.mult(0));
  }

  // relation : add (rel_op add)*;
  visitRelation(ctx) {
    if (ctx.add().length > 1) {
      const v1 = this.visit(ctx.add(0));
      const v2 = this.visit(ctx.add(1));
      const operator = this.visit(ctx.rel_op());

      if (operator == '=') {
        return v1 == v2;
      }
      else {
        throw new Error('Operator not implemented: `' + operator + '`');
      }
    }

    return this.visit(ctx.add(0));
  }

  // expression : relation ((AND | OR) relation)*;
  visitExpression(ctx) {
    // TODO account for multiple `relation`s
    return this.visit(ctx.relation(0));
  }

  // function : FUNCTION_NAME OPEN_ROUND_BRACKET (expression (COMMA expression)*)? CLOSE_ROUND_BRACKET;
  visitFunction(ctx) {
    // Assume there is only 1 type of function: an IF with 3 expressions
    const e1 = this.visit(ctx.expression(0));
    const e2 = this.visit(ctx.expression(1));
    const e3 = this.visit(ctx.expression(2));
    console.log('e1:', e1, ', e2:', e2, ', e2:', e3);
    return e1 === true ? e2 : e3;
  }

  // term : function | INTEGER | DECIMAL | PERCENT | reference | OPEN_ROUND_BRACKET expression CLOSE_ROUND_BRACKET;
  visitTerm(ctx) {
    if (ctx.function_() != null) return this.visit(ctx.function_());
    if (ctx.INTEGER() != null) return parseInt(ctx.INTEGER().getText());
    if (ctx.reference() != null) return this.visit(ctx.reference());
    throw new Error('TODO: implement other terms');
  }

  // reference : CELL;
  visitReference(ctx) {
    return ctx.CELL().getText();
  }

  // rel_op : RELATION_SYMBOL | ST;
  visitRel_op(ctx) {
    return ctx.RELATION_SYMBOL() == null ? ctx.ST().getText() : ctx.RELATION_SYMBOL().getText();
  }
}
```

which can be tested with the following `main.js`:

```js
import antlr4 from 'antlr4';
import MyGrammarLexer from './MyGrammarLexer.js';
import MyGrammarParser from './MyGrammarParser.js';
import DemoVisitor from './DemoVisitor.js';

const input = "=IF(D169=D169,100,4242)";
const lexer = new MyGrammarLexer(new antlr4.InputStream(input));
const parser = new MyGrammarParser(new antlr4.CommonTokenStream(lexer));
const visitor = new DemoVisitor();
const result = visitor.visit(parser.formula());

console.log('result:', result);
```

My `package.json` looks like this:

```json
{
  "name": "antlr4-demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./main.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "antlr4": "^4.13.1-patch-1"
  }
}
```

If you now run this file with `npm run start`, you will see this on your console:

```
e1: true , e2: 100 , e2: 4242
result: 100
```